# The request entity cannot be empty

Tags: web-services, jakarta-ee, jersey, jax-rs, http-status-code-400

> I am new to Jax-RS. I am trying to implement a simple GET method using
>   jersey. I am getting the correct output for the Collection resource,
>   but I am getting **"ERROR 400 Bad Request"** for instance resource . I
>   am stuck at this point. Everything seems to be correct,but I am
>   missing something which I am not able to figure out. I have been
>   trying it for last 10 days. Any help will be appreciable. Please find
>   my code below.I am using POSTMAN rest client which is throwing
>   "Unexpected 'T'" as response and ARC is throwing "The request entity
>   cannot be empty." and both are Error 400 bad request.

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
    id="WebApp_ID" version="3.1">
    <display-name>MessangerWithoutMaven</display-name>
    <welcome-file-list>

        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>

    </welcome-file-list>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

This is my MessageResource.java :

```
package com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.resources;

import java.util.List;

import javax.websocket.server.PathParam;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;

import com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.model.Message;
import com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.service.MessageService;

@Path("/messages")
public class MessageResource {

    MessageService messageService = new MessageService();
    @GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public List<Message> getMessages(){

        return messageService.getAllMessages();
    }

    @GET
    @Path("/{id}")
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public Message getMessage(@PathParam("id") int id){


        return messageService.getMessage(id);
    }

}
```

This is  DaoClass.java:

```
package com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.Dao;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.model.Message;


public class DaoClass {


    private static Map<Integer,Message> messages = new HashMap<Integer,Message>();


    public static Map<Integer, Message> getMessages() {
        return messages;
    }
}
```

This is MessageService.java:

```
package com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.service;

    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Map;

    import com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.Dao.DaoClass;
    import com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.model.Message;

    public class MessageService {

        private Map<Integer,Message> messages= DaoClass.getMessages();

        Message m1= new Message(1,"Hello John","John");
        Message m2=  new Message(2,"Hello Mathews","Mathews");
        Message m3= new Message(3,"Hello Albert","Albert");

        public MessageService(){
            messages.put(1,m1);
            messages.put(2,m2);
            messages.put(3, m3);
        }
        public List<Message> getAllMessages(){
            return new ArrayList<Message>(messages.values());
        }
        public Message getMessage(int id){
            return messages.get(id);
        }
    }
```

This is Message.java:

```
package com.manish.jax_rs.Messanger.model;

import java.util.Date;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Message {

    private int id;
    private String message;
    //private Date created;
    private String author;

    public Message() {

    }
    public Message(int id, String message, String author) {

        this.id = id;
        this.message = message;
        this.author = author;
        //this.created = new Date();
    }

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }
    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }
    public String getMessage() {
        return message;
    }
    public void setMessage(String message) {
        this.message = message;
    }

    public String getAuthor() {
        return author;
    }
    public void setAuthor(String author) {
        this.author = author;
    }
}



[List of jars][1]




[correct output for collection resource "messages" in Postman rest client][2]


[Incorrect output for instance resource /messages/1][3]enter code here


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sWfMl.jpg
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/y5Nnf.jpg
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8CwId.jpg
```

Answer (score 16):

Please check your import of PathParam.
Instead of "javax.websocket.server.PathParam;" use "import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;". 
This should work fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why this change should solve the issue?

Comment: answers should be detailed please update your answer

Comment: I really could not find what was the issue. Just imported the same project to STS and it worked like  charm .

Answer (score 1):

You have imported import javax.websocket.server.PathParam; which should be import javax.ws.rs.PathParam;

Comment: This is just a duplicate of another answer